# PostgreSQL: Increment otherwise insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have rows which are updated with an increment very often, but inserted very rarely. Is it possible to switch the order of the new `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` statement to optimize for updates instead of inserts?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
INSERT INTO ?? (??) VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT(??) DO UPDATE SET ?? = ?? + 1 RETURNING ??
```

While this works, it also increases the sequence for the primary key each time even if the insert fails.

Is it possible to rewrite the query in a way that the first operation would be an update, and only if no update executed an insert would be performed?

Answer (score 0):

I know no builtin command for that but you can write a stored procedure for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_or_insert(in_parameter1 INTEGER, ...) RETURNING SETOF my_table AS $$
DECLARE
    result my_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    WITH updated_rows AS (
        UPDATE my_table SET ... WHERE ... RETURNING *
    )
    SELECT * INTO result FROM updated_rows;
    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN NEXT result;
    ELSE
        WITH inserted_rows AS (
            INSERt INTO my_table (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *
        )
        SELECT * INTO result FROM inserted_rows;
        RETURN NEXT result;
    END IF;
RETURN;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can call this function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM update_or_insert(123, ...);
```